# Base Map for openLayers 6 with BNG EPSG:27700

Tags: openlayers, bng

Which base Map can I use in OpenLayers 6 with the British National Grid EPSG:27700 coordinate system?

I am new to OpenLayers and trying to follow examples available using JavaScript on a local webserver. I don't use NodeJS which means all those import commands in those examples are useless and I struggle to reuse the code to point to local copied OL objects.

A simple code example explaining which Basemap to use and how to register EPSG:27700 in OpenLayers and use the get.

For example, instead of using this example from OpenLayers but not using 'import ...' command because I am using `ol` locally and on a Windows IIS web server.

```py
import proj4 from 'proj4';   
proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:27700',
  '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 ' +
    '+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy ' +
    '+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 ' +
    '+units=m +no_defs'

register(proj4); 
//then
const proj27700 = getProjection('EPSG:27700');
```

Comment: There are examples of EPSG:27700 base maps using the OpenLayers legacy build at https://labs.os.uk/public/openspace-migration/examples/basic-map

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, was a very good link and source of information i was looking for.